# set selected value to bean to respective input fields

Tags: spring-mvc, primefaces

i have my dialog this

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<p:dialog header="Look Up" width="400px" resizable="false" modal="true"
    widgetVar="dlg200">
    <p:dataTable style="font-size:13px;" paginatorPosition="bottom"
        id="dialoglov" var="lov" value="#{mmsBean.admlovs}"
        selection="#{mmsBean.selectedadmlovs}" selectionMode="single"
        resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150"
        rowKey="#{lov.id}" rows="5" paginator="false"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
        emptyMessage="No data found with given criteria ">
        <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" oncomplete="PF('dlg200').hide()" />
        <p:column style="font-size:13px;" headerText="Code"
            sortBy="#{lov.code}" filterBy="#{lov.code}"
            filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText style="font-size:13px;" value="#{lov.code}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="font-size:13px;" headerText="Description"
            sortBy="#{lov.descr}" filterBy="#{lov.descr}"
            filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText style="font-size:13px;" value="#{lov.descr}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton value="Select" onclick="PF('dlg200').hide()"
        style="margin-top:10px !important" />
</p:dialog>
```

and from which the dialogue is calling is

```
    <div class="col-md-12 " style="margin-top: 2% !important;">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
            <p:outputLabel styleClass="WhiteBlue" value="Estimated" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h:inputText type="text" styleClass="form-control"
               id="fvar" value="#{pmBean.selectedadmlovs.code}"
               title="Estimated Cost Of WorkOrder" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h:inputText type="text" styleClass="form-control"
               id="fvaar" value="#{pmBean.selectedadmlovs.descr}"
               title="Estimated Cost Currency" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <p:commandButton onclick="PF('dlg200').show();"
              action="#{lovController.lovForFincurrency('fincurrency:fvar')}"
              icon="fa fa-search Fs12 White                                 
              styleClass="BlueTextButton" process="@this"
              update="dialoglov fvar" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

i want to set the selected value from dialogue to both of input fields
there are too many input fields so and one dialogue. when ever the dialogue is open and user select the value from it, it should set the value respectively to that particular field. i want to make generic 
thanks

Comment: If you are using same bean properties for outer screen and dialog then values will be changing but not updated on UI. Therefore, just update that portion of outer screen on closing the dialog.

Comment: yes you are rite but iam using different beans for outer screen and dialogue

Comment: Then you need to `actionListener` on your Select `p:commandButton` and set other bean's properties in it. Also, remember to update that portion as well.

Comment: PrimeFaces cannot run on spring-mvc...

Comment: And please create a [mcve]